# Web page on refresh, mysql update

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have web page which has a DB connection with an update statement. I have a `submit button`, on clicking the button, the DB needs to be updated. But on accessing the specific page or refreshing the page, it automatically updates the DB. I have not set any function or anything else.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php 

$connect=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root',"web");
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $query = "UPDATE student AS t1 
              INNER JOIN employer AS t2 ON t1.stud_location = t2.emp_location 
              SET t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id";
    $search_result =mysqli_query($connect,$query); 
} else { 
    $query = "UPDATE student AS t1 
              INNER JOIN employer AS t2 ON t1.stud_location = t2.emp_location 
              SET t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id";
    $search_result =mysqli_query($connect,$query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, your query is run whether `submit` is set or not. You probably want to remove it from the `else` clause.

Comment: you mean deleting the else statement?

Comment: tried but then get elsewhere faults.. Can u confirm if i should use only if statement and not else ?

Comment: You're the only person who knows the logic of what you're trying to do. If you want to run your UPDATE only when the form is submitted, then no, you don't need an else statement at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated you want to only update when the form is submitted, if so your best option is to go with $_POST instead of $_GET. Also, you are telling your page that if $_GET['submit'] exists run this, else if it doesn't exist run this (which is the same as if it does exist.) You should read [PHP dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)
If you want the query to run ONLY if the form has been submitted you should have the following:

```
    <?php 

$connect=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root',"web");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = "UPDATE student AS t1 INNER JOIN employer AS t2 ON t1.stud_location = t2.emp_location SET t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id";
    $search_result =mysqli_query($connect,$query); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. and for the link also.. Thanks again